# Calling C# (.NET6) from Ansi C [DllExport]

Tags: c#, c, .net-6.0, dllexport, unmanagedexports

following example:

```
public static class DLLExportMethode
{
    [DllExport("add", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static int Add(int left, int right)
    {
        return left + right;
    }
}
```

Errors:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>
> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'DllExportAttribute' could not
> be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)   CallingCSharpFromAnsiC.Library
>
> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'DllExport' could not be found
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)   CallingCSharpFromAnsiC.Library
>
> Error CS1069  The type name 'CallingConvention' could not be found in
> the namespace 'System.Runtime.InteropServices'. This type has been
> forwarded to assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices,
> Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
> Consider adding a reference to that
> assembly. CallingCSharpFromAnsiC.Library

but something is missing?

Does anyone have a simple example or know what is missing? Or how the syntax is correct.
I would not want to use third party libraries for export.

Comment: .net does not have this built in - you'll have to add support for it - https://github.com/3F/DllExport

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DllExport#readme-body-tab

Answer (score -1):

Your fundamental problem is that a native C executable has no .NET runtime, and can't directly call a C# dll. What you really need to do is have a C dll that is loaded by a C# executable, and you use P/Invoke to generate function pointers for C# methods that can be passed to your C code.

See this for a minimalistic example [Using PInvoke in C# with function pointer and delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059647/using-pinvoke-in-c-sharp-with-function-pointer-and-delegate)

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you may want a simple C# application that loads any other C# dlls you want your C code to be able to call, create delegates for whatever you need, call a C function to provide all the function pointers to the native C code, and finally call a entry point in your C dll (i.e. what would have been your C main).

You can also get quite fancy with reflecting objects to get function pointers for methods against specific objects (i.e. non-static), but from your question I think you are only looking to call static methods.